# Opencv HOG Runtime Exception

Tags: windows, visual-studio, opencv, runtime-error

I have the following code;

```
EducateHOG(string file){
    Mat image = imread(file);
    vector <float> desc;
    vector <Point> locs;

    resize(image, image, Size(64,48));
    cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    HogDescriptor hog(Size(32,16), Size(8,8), Size(4,4), Size(4,4), 9);
    hog.compute(image, desc, Size(0,0), Size(0,0), lots); //This cause error
}
```

It just reads a simple image with a car in it but hog.compute(...) causes runtime errors as below:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF... (msvcr120.dll) .... Access violating writing location 0x0000258....
```

I use Visual Studio 2015 with OpenCv libraries on Win 10. I couldn't find the cause of this error.

Comment: I have other codes working with OpenCv libraries (HOG is not used). So I don't think its from OpenCv integration. It works fine.

Comment: msvcr120.dll is not compatible with Visual Studio 2015

Comment: So how can I fix that. I did not even specifically put it.

Comment: AFAIK you must to built OpenCV libraries from source

Comment: take a look at [this tutorial](http://funvision.blogspot.be/2015/11/install-opencv-visual-studio-2015.html)

Answer (score 0):

In project properties, where you linking library of Opencv. In `linker -> Input -> Aditional dependencies` make sure in debug configuration, you have only opencv_**300d.lib.(every lib where is "D"). I had also that without opencv_ts300.lib , and it build ok. But when run in debug it throw that exception on .hog.compute